# How to Combine Post Install in Podfile in React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I need to add the following post install to the Podfile.

```
post_install do |pi|
  pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
    t.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

But encountered this error.

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Specifying multiple `post_install` hooks is unsupported..
```

There are two post install in the Podfile. How should I combine them to resolve the error?

```
post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

post_install do |pi|
  pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
    t.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11):

The following seems to work

```
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
      t.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
      end
    end
  end
```